# How to set Oracle SQL Developer automatically wrap long SQL statements

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer, some queries are too long to show in one line, so I must use the scroll bar to see the hidden text on the right side.

How can I make Oracle SQL Developer to automatically wrap long query onto a new line?

[image: My query]]

Comment: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/forcing-line-breaks-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: where is the menu 'Oracle – Line Breaks – Threshold for small SQL', i can't find it, my version is 18.1.0

Comment: See my answer @Huage.org - the preferences have changed since that post in 2012. I'm updating the post now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no 'auto transform my code', but we do have the formatter.

The formatter has rules. There is a rule which will control the max length of a line of code.

Set the Max char line width preference in the formatter.

Then format your code (ctrl+F7)

[image]

It's not absolute, however.

Below is a screenshot of the setting set to 45, also with the visible line gutter set to also 45 (and red), with some formatted code.

Note I've also told the formatter NOT to insert carriage returns before or after commas in a SELECT or FROM.

[image]

We don't cut the text off, mid word...instead, we force a line break at the next whole word.
What I suggest instead is investigate the preferences around line breaks in general - of which there are MANY.

As you tweak the preferences, you can see your sample code format in real time, so you know what the true effect is.

Comment: Thanks thatjeffsmith. I find the setting in preferences, and i do it follow your suggestion. Maybe i didn't make myself clear, i hope sql developer auto turn to next line when i wirte sql which is longer than the window, just like MS Word.

Comment: @Huage.org we don't have an automatic formatting feature, but you can easily format your code whenever you want

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to thatjeffsmith

```
CTRL+F7
```

Will convert from one-line to formated code. Not a direct answer to the question, but a better solution to my similar question/problem.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer seem to be out-of-date.
For PL/SQL Developer v. 12.0.7.1837 you can go to

Configure > Preferences > User Interface - Editor > Tabs & Wrapping - Wrap lines.

[image]

Comment: we are talk about  Oracle SQL Developer, not PL/SQL Developer, they have many different